# Keybinding for :edit! - <F1>

Tags: vim

I know we could refresh our pages in Vim by using `:edit!` in Vim. I would like a keybinding for such thing, because I use frequently that command. Could anyone be able to tell me how could I do such thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily map new keybindings in vim by editing `.vimrc`

```
nmap <F1> xvmap :edit!
```

This will only work on normal mode (**n**map)

More [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/create-custom-keybindings-in-vim/)

Answer (score 0):

in  $HOME/.vimrc add:

`map <F2> :edit!`

source: [newbiedoc](http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/tutorials/vim/mapping-vim.html.en)